# How can I specify a local port when establishing SSH connections?

Tags: ssh, networking

I have two servers hosted in IDC. I can only use ports 20/21/22/23/3389/33101-33109 to establish connections between two servers. The IDC network device will block any other packets whose source or destination port is not in the 20/21/22/23/80/3389/33101-33109 list/range. But the source port of SSH is random.

Using the command
`ssh username@server -p remote_port`
one can easily specify a remote port.

So is there an `ssh` command parameter or some other way to specify a local source port so I can use, for example, port 33101 to establish the SSH connection?

My network topology is like this:
[image: network topology]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can not specify the source port for ssh client.

But you can use `nc` as a proxy, like this:

```
ssh -p 33101 -o 'ProxyCommand nc -p 33101 %h %p' $SERVER_2
```

From [*How can i set the source port for SSH on unbuntu server?* (on ServerFault)](//serverfault.com/a/920028).

Answer (score 2):

For one-off, or anyway occasional, situations the ProxyCommand approach is easily a very convenient one.

On the other hand, if you need several simultaneous connections, or when perhaps you need to use that command frequently for daily work, you might also instead consider to set a network-address-translation (NAT) rule on your server.

This requires superuser (typically `root`) access on your server to first apply the one single NAT rule. Note that it *might* not be allowed (or effective) at all to apply the NAT rule, even when you have superuser access, if your "server" is actually a container (like a Docker one) instead of a machine.

Speaking of a typical Linux system with the `iptables` suite, the NAT rule to apply on your server1 for your sample case could be like:

```bash
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -d <server2-ip-address> -p tcp --dport <server2-port> -j SNAT --to :33101-33109
```

That command instructs the Linux kernel to make any connections towards port *server2-port* of *server2-ip-address* to go out using a source port chosen within the range 33101-33109 that is available at that moment.

Once that rule is in place, you connect to your server2 just with your usual:

```
ssh username@server2 -p remote_port
```

and you could use this same `ssh` command also concurrently for as many times as you need, as long as there are available ports in the range specified in the NAT rule.

Note however that a `netstat` (or equivalent command) run on your server reports the connection's local address as being the *unmodified*, randomly chosen, source port number even though the actual traffic that is delivered to your server2 carries the *modified* source port number.

To undo the NAT rule, the command is the same except for a `-D` option in place of the `-I`.

To have the NAT rule applied automatically at boot depends on what Linux distribution you have on your server, and on whether it already has some firewall configuration in place or not.

I have no experience with BSD-like systems, but I trust there is an equivalent.